# Find files containing text in the name and move saving permissions to another folder

Tags: linux, bash, debian, permissions

I've got asterisk srecords in mp3 format with naming like 13-07-31__09-32_205_988007007757.mp3 in /etc/asterisk/record

I need to select files, containing, for example `*_205_*` and move them to folder /home/ftp saving permisions.

My only way was:

```
cp -p /home/zapis/liveop/*_205_* "/home/zapis/livetex/dep1/205/"

rm /home/zapis/liveop/_205_
```

but I recieve error `failed to stat «/home/zapis/liveop/*_205_*»: No such file or directory`

And it looks not good at all:(

Comment: This error usually occurs, if no file matches your pattern. Are you absolutely sure the file exists where you expect it and that you did not mistype anything? Also why are you quoting the destination?

Comment: I just saw that you edited the error message quite a few times. If you did not copy and paste but retype all in- and output: Be sure that you did not quote the source term (with the `*`) when typing the command. This will prevent bash expansion from matching the files with your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

if i were you, i would do it this way

```
find /home/zapis/loveop -name "*_250_*" -exec cp {} /home/zapis/livetex/dep1/205/ ';'
find /home/zapis/loveop -name "*_250_*" -exec rm {} ';'
```

cp, rm and coreutils stuff have limitation on operating on maximum number of files, this is in fact shell limitation on number of arguments that one command could receive.